# Does Aerospike have something similar to HBase's co-processor?

Tags: aerospike

HBase's co-processor is a good example of "moving calculations not data". Not sure if Aerospike support something similar to this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aerospike supports user-defined functions (UDFs), which are functions users load in to the database and execute.

Aerospike provides two types of UDF, record and stream, both of which are equivalent to HBase's Endpoint coprocessors, in that they execute against the data and return a result. The record UDF is executed against a single record, allowing for record modifications and calculations on a single record. The stream UDF is executed against query results, providing ability to analyze or aggregate the data. Both UDF execute on the node containing the data, and return a user-defined result.

Aerospike does not support the concept of HBase's Observer coprocessors, which are executed based on an event.

Comment: Thanks! the streaming UDF is what I needed. I need to do some aggregations on server side to reduce the data transferred on network.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't quite a direct answer to your question, but VoltDB supports near-arbitrary Java processing in the database process local to the partition of data you're interested in. You can mix Java and SQL in a fully transactional environment and still scale to millions of ACID transactions per second.

Comment: I need some features like TTL support of aerospike.

Comment: Also note that VoltDB is in-memory, rendering it kinda useless for huge datasets or strong persistency needs. It got a very narrow usecase, imho.